# Copy/Paste areas aren't the same size

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting an error that I was not getting before with this VBA code:

```
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Range("A1:H100").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If fileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    MsgBox "File salvato al percorso " & fileSaveName & "."
    End If

      ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$100").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

telling me that copy/paste areas are not the same. What I'm trying to do is filter results, copy them and paste in a new workbook, save it as .txt and unfilter on the original workbook.

thanks for your assistance!

S

Comment: Hi, the error is happening because, the cells which are copied can not be pasted in the selected area because the  copy size and paste size is different. Just try selecting a different location, may be cell 1,1 of sheet two before you paste, it will work. Tried & Works at my end.

Comment: @ApurvPawar Why don't you post an answer? Like this the rest of us can see that someone has (potentially) already found a solution and that this question does not require our attention anymore. Furthermore, it allows Selene to accept your answer and thus mark this question as solved: giving points to both of you and making life easier for the rest of us. What do you think?

Comment: @Ralph Thanks, Done, should have done it at first place itself

Answer (score 1):

the error is happening because, the cells which are copied can not be pasted in the selected area because the copy size and paste size is different. Just try selecting a different location, may be cell 1,1 of sheet two before you paste, it will work. Tried & Works at my end.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim dwb As Workbook
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With Range("A1:H100")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    If Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        dwb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    .AutoFilter field:=1
End With
```